# Dom-to-image SVG image elements

Tags: image, d3.js, svg

I'm using the brilliant [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) to capture a screenshot of a d3.js dashboard and download as a png.

I've found it works better than it's competitors - the CSS transfers beautifully - but I've come across a stumbling block.

I have some SVG image elements in my dashboard:

```
<image x="20" y="20" width="300"height="80" 
xlink:href="image/my_image.png"/>
```

These are either embedded directly onto the svg or as pattern definitions and they are not rendering on the PNG.

This is a [know problem](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues/60) and one which has come up on Stack Overflow before but I haven't been able to find a solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: can you describe what do you mean but stumbling block? doesn't render or what is happening? can you elaborate what the issue is? image tag  is a perfect member of SVG standard and unless you describe why you are blocked its unclear how to help you.

Comment: The problem is that the plug in (dom-to-image) does not support SVG images.  Only HTML images.

Comment: So the HTML page and all the SVG elements render perfectly (including CSS which is pretty cool) but not the SVG images.

Comment: Why you need png?

Comment: Not sure that's helpful.  I've actually solved it by going into the code and adding SVG compatibility myself.

Comment: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues/253

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your svg converted to png. Just place your nodeRef in a div and inside that div let your d3.js component be written.Applying nodeRef directly over component will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was installing [html-to-image](https://github.com/bubkoo/html-to-image) and not using `dom-to-image`

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I didn't know this library existed. It works great. html-to-image seems to work much more consistently than dom-to-image and html2canvas for capturing screenshots since I just started using it.